# Uploading custom Drupal module to drupal.org or marketplace

Tags: plugins, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I developed a custom Drupal module for an organisation. I want to know if we can upload the Drupal module in the Drupal Marketplace or on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/). If possible, how ?
Also If uploading is not possible, how can we contribute the module?

Answer (score 0):

this is a document about how to create a full project on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org) 
[doc_page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1068942)

after this you need to upload your code on Drupal repository.
for this use [this document](https://www.drupal.org/node/1997092) 
finally apply for approval is your project approve then your project become as approved project and should be available to download on your project page URL
like this drupal.org/project/yourModuleName

you will find many more information about it on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org)

hoop this help
THANKS!